# Is Gekko Moriah human?

Tags: one-piece

Obviously, Gekko Moriah is pretty funky looking.  I understand that his horns and wings are articles of clothing but his size, neck, and leek-like appearance are strange.  In a forum discussing fan theories concerning the nature of "minkmen" someone wrote that Oda confirmed Moriah to be a human (as opposed to fishman or snakeneck) and therefore "anything is possible".  I've been unable to find his source.

I am not asking if Moriah is a snakeneck or minkmen as I believe they have not yet been shown/identified by official sources.  What I am asking is: are there any official sources that identify whether Moriah is human?

Comment: Note: right now Minkmen are all shown to have hair similar to a specific mammal.  This seems to exclude that race.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've yet to see an interview or article from Oda's words about Gekko Moriah concerning his race unless it was noted by Oda somewhere on the Japanese side of the fandom and it was overlooked and never translated...

However, the manga's latest arc is going to be dealing with Kaido, Moriah's greatest enemy, and I expect him to pop up soon. Hopefully, Oda will give us more detail on Moriah's background and make a side story explaining how exactly did his old crew get massacred (which I hope for cause I really wanna see Moriah back when he was young and badass.)

Comment: Well, after Donflamingo gets roasted by Law and the Strawhats first. XD

Comment: So the answer is that there is no currently known answer as I expected.  Excellent.  This answer will do nicely until things change.

Answer (score 0):

This is all we know about him being a human :-

> Moriah is a gargantuan person with very distinct devil-like features.
>   Standing at 22' 7'' in height, he is the tallest among the
>   Shichibukai. His animal theme is that of a gecko based off his name,
>   general appearance and the collar of his shirt bearing a resemblance
>   to a lizard's frilled neck. His overall design resembles a giant leek

Wiki [Source](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Gekko_Moriah)

Comment: So as far as you know too, we don't know for certain what type of person he is from canon sources? (the wiki usually takes from canon but is itself not nessesarily accurate)